# Magento Unique Key error with Inventory and SAP

Tags: php, magento, sap-erp

I'm trying to configure Magento using SAP as a back end.

I have connected to the SAP system using PHP script. And also I have added data to it. Now I'm trying to update the added data, but I'm stuck on an error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:    Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '298-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228

Stack trace:

> #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>
> #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_ in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a full reindex from System>Index Management in the admin. If that fails, truncate the `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` table and reindex, then run your script again.

Comment: i did the steps you suggested but now I'm getting following SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '291-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::update(Array ( ) )' in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Object.php:652 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\ProductException.php(74): Varien_Object->__call('update', Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\ProductException.php(74): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->update() #2 {main}

Comment: i think you need to post your code. it sounds like there is a bug in the way that it is trying to create inventory

Comment: In the first part I'm connecting to SAP server.Then using following code I'm adding the data to magento.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setSku($user["MATNR"]);
$product->setName($user["MATL_DESC"]);
$product->setDescription("NEW PRODUCT");
$product->setShortDescription("NEW ");
$product->setPrice($user["PRICE"]);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);
$product->setCategoryIds("61"); 
$product->setWeight(1.0);
$product->setTaxClassId(2);
$product->setVisibility(4); 
$product->setStatus(1); And i'm not able to update this data.

Comment: I'm getting sku,price,material description from SAP.So if i change the values of these in SAP,then i cannot  update them in magento.Kindly help me in this.

Comment: please post your code samples in your question and format it so that we can actually read it

Comment: `**$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product->setSku($user["MATNR"]);
$product->setName($user["MATL_DESC"]);
$product->setDescription("NEW PRODUCT");
$product->setShortDescription("NEW ");
$product->setPrice($user["PRICE"]);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(9); // need to look this up
$product->setCategoryIds("61"); // need to look these up
$product->setWeight(1.0);
$product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
$product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
$product->setStatus(1); // enabled**`

Comment: Edit your question. don't post a comment with code, its impossible to read. Stack Overflow doesn't work like a bulletin board with threaded messages.

Comment: `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setSku($user["MATNR"]);
$product->setName($user["MATL_DESC"]);
$product->setDescription("NEW PRODUCT");
$product->setShortDescription("NEW ");
$product->setPrice($user["PRICE"]);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(9); 
$product->setCategoryIds("61"); 
$product->setWeight(1.0);
$product->setTaxClassId(2); 
$product->setVisibility(4); 
$product->setStatus(1);`  **I want to update only the price field in magento when it is changed in SAP***

Comment: Issue solved.Thanks for your help.Keep up the good work.Thanks again.

Comment: Please can you post the solution if you found one so others can benefit?

Answer (score 0):

If one has installed the extension "Market Ready Germany", you need to make sure your browser is sending a referrer – otherwise the above error will occur. (With no hint on the referrer…)